# Создать многомерный массив в цикле

Tags: php

Допустим, имеем массив:

`$b = ['a', 'b', 'c',];`

Понятно как сделать из него максимум двумерный массив, пропустить через цикл

```php
for($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
  $q[$x] = ['$b[$x]' => ' '];   
}
```

Возможно ли сделать из него многомерный массив, вложенных друг в друга массивов:

```
$a = ['a' => [ 'd' => [ 'c' => '']]];
```

Comment: были такие вопросы уже, что то не могу найти (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array = array_reverse($array);

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result = [
        $value => $result
    ];
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Конечно](https://ideone.com/A1vxHP)

```
$b = ['a', 'b', 'c',];
$a = [];
$tmp = &$a;
foreach($b as $v) {
  $tmp[$v] = [];
  $tmp = &$tmp[$v];
}
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вы так хотели?

```
$arr = [];
$b = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$link = &$arr;

for($i=0, $len=sizeof($b); $i<$len; $i++){
  $link = [$b[$i]=> []];
  $link = &$link[$b[$i]];

}
var_dump($arr);

?>
```